# ApostropheCMS - Remove Page Menu from user group guest

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have an instance of ApostropheCMS with two user groups, admin and guest. I'd love to hide the Page Menu for the guest users. After all, it is empty.

Would love it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this, but I handled this by adding a style block to my outerLayout.html file that only gets shown when someone is on a page that they don't have permission to edit.

The class for the Page Menu button is .apos-ui .apos-context-menu-container. My code ended up looking like this:

```
  {% if data.piece._edit or data.page._edit %}
    // Other special stuff that only editors should see
  {% else %}
    <style>
    .apos-ui .apos-context-menu-container {
      display: none !important;
    }
    </style>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply overwrite the apostrophe-ui module add public/js/always.less 
add this always.less file in your module and overwrite the css part within always.less

modules/apostrophe-ui/public/always.less

```
.apos-ui .apos-context-menu-container {
      display: none !important;
    }
```

modules/apostrophe-ui/index.js

```
module.exports = {

  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Custom widget',
  contextualOnly: true,
  scene: 'user',
  construct: function(self, options) {
     self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'always', { when: 'always' });
}
```

This solution work for me.